# Why a keystore can have multiple certificate in it?

Tags: android, apk, code-signing-certificate

I would like to be sure I understand well the apk signing process.

So an apk is signed by linking it to a certificate (identity of the developer) OK

It is materialized with a keystore file.

But concretely what does this file contain? That is what I am not quite sure about and I find online resources explanations confusing.

From my understanding:

The keystore contains a list of "keys"or "certificates" that are concretely a pair alias/password  or (private/public key).

Signing a apk is concretely linking the apk to a specific certificate which is possible by joining the right keystore and entering the right alias and password.

Am I right? If yes what is the use of storing multiple certificates in a single keystore file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Keystore may contains list of keyAlias , because you can use one keystore for your all applications , so when you release your new app , you use your usual keystore with creating new keyAlias in it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So when we create a keystore and we add alias/password/certificate  it's these three things that are encrypted and designated as private key? Is it why we say the keystore is a set of private keys?

Comment: yes of course , keystore itself means set of keys, for more information , you can read https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#considerations